# Use srun to execute code once, but with multiple tasks

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, slurm, hpc

I am currently trying to run some ORCA calculations on a HPC cluster, that does not support ssh. Since ORCA is really write intensive, I want to run it within the memory using the /dev/shm/ location. Instead of using ssh, I have now tried to use srun, but am struggling finding the right set of parameters.

The code structure is basically a loop over the nodes, and a loop over the number of calculations per node, and each one calls:

```
for  (( j=1; j<=$N_nodes; j++ ))
do
 for (( i=1; i<=$N_calc; i++ ))
 do
  node=$(awk '{print $1}' host_${j}_${C_num})
  Node_number=${node:5}
  export TMP_DIR=/dev/shm/CALC_${i}_${j}_${C_num}
  srun  --overlap --jobid=$SLURM_JOB_ID -N 1 --ntasks=$N_Tasks --cpus-per-task=$CPUs -w nid00$Node_number $SHELL execute.sh $j $i
sleep 20
 done
done
```

with execute.sh being a simple script that just loads the modules and then executes the loop_i_j_C_num.sh script. Within that script, and ORCA executable that requires 8 cores is started multiple times, until all tasks are done.

However, for the srun command, I am unsure about the right parameters. I tried two versions:

N_Tasks=1, CPUs=8:
This results in ORCA not being able to start the calculations, as it requires 8 MPI tasks, but onyl one is allowed.

N_Tasks=8, CPUs=1:
This results in the execute.sh program being executed 8 times, instead of just once.

How do I tell srun to start the code once, but with 8 CPUs and tasks?

Comment: `srun -N 1 -n 8 ...` starts 8 MPI tasks on a single node. The `execute.sh` script will be executed 8 times, but I suspect it will invoke a MPI application that will be part of the same MPI job. since the MPI jobs are run in sequence and on a single node (very likely the same) I do not understand why you are using `srun` (`mpirun` should simply fork&exec the tasks so there should not be any need for `ssh`).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The reason I need to use srun is, since I am running on multiple nodes, each task needs to move a number of files into the /dev/shm location, which is unique for each node. So the goal is to have the srun start a task once (per loop), which then moves the files into the memory and can then execute the ORCA script which utilizes 8 cores with OpenMPI.

Comment: `srun -N 1` runs all the tasks on the same node. If you want to run 8 tasks on 8 nodes (e.g. one task per node) then `srun -N 8 -n 8`

Comment: OK, it seems I missed the `--overlap` flag. if `srun -N 1 -n 8 ...` ends up running 8 independant MPI jobs of size 1 (instead of a single job of size 8) it means your MPI library does not support `srun` and hence runs in singleton mode. you should first double check that with a simple MPI hello world app.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet `mpirun` is not available on all HPC systems. On some systems 
(e.g. HPE Cray EX) you are often mandated to use `srun` as the parallel executable launcher if they use Slurm as the job scheduler.

Comment: sure, and on those systems `srun` is supposed to work as it should with the MPI library, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! I am still a little confused, but the that might be coming from me not being completely clear about the goal?

The whole thing is contained in a slurm script, which requests two entire nodes, 128 each cores each. I then want to run 16 of these subjobs per node, with each using 8 cores. But I can either get 16 jobs that have 1 task each, or 16 calls that create 8 jobs each, but not 16 jobs with 1 jobs with 8 tasks available each, if that makes sense?

Comment: I think there is some confusion about what a job is. `srun` simply spawn tasks. so `srun -N 1 -n 8 ...` will spawn 8 tasks on the same node. If a task is a MPI program and your MPI library supports `srun`, then they will act as a single MPI application (e.g. `MPI_COMM_WORLD` has size `8`). If you spawn a script/wrapper, then this script/wrapper will be executed 8 times. I guess you posting your `execute.sh` script will clear the confusion.

Comment: FWIW if what you want to achieve is basically run your own batch manager within a SLURM allocation, you might want to consider `flux` http://flux-framework.org/

Comment: I suspect one issue is that your srun command is calling a shell script which is then calling the executable. What you end up doing is launching 8 copies of the shell script with each 8 task srun and then each of these copies of the shell script launches a single process MPI executable. What happens if you call the MPI executable directly via srun rather than launching via the script?

Comment: There is documentation and some examples of running multiple job steps within a batch script using srun at: https://docs.archer2.ac.uk/user-guide/scheduler/#using-multiple-srun-commands-in-a-single-job-script . But, as each sites Slurm config will be different you may need to modify it for your system.

Comment: @AndyT That would be ideal, but the script essentially moves all the files into the local storage of the node, and then creates a loop that periodically calls the ORCA executable multiple times